# NextJS serves some text instead of html

Tags: next.js

My nextJS app is serving, sometimes, a text with some `static` content instead of the actual html

```
1:HL["/_next/static/media/7777133e901cd5ed-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}]
2:HL["/_next/static/media/916d3686010a8de2-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}]
3:HL["/_next/static/media/9a881e2ac07d406b-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}]
4:HL["/_next/static/media/c04551857776278f-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}]
5:HL["/_next/static/media/d869208648ca5469-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}]
6:HL["/_next/static/css/23bb12ed1ea5f9c7.css",{"as":"style"}]
0:[[["",{"children":["__PAGE__",{}]},"$undefined","$undefined",true],"$L7",[[["$","link","0",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/23bb12ed1ea5f9c7.css","precedence":"next"}]],["$L8",["$","meta",null,{"name":"next-size-adjust"}]]]]]
9:I{"id":"46828","chunks":["3629:static/chunks/3629-0f2957a3da16c20f.js","8707:static/chunks/8707-2b2cb7694746a12d.js","2046:static/chunks/2046-d5dab6937324b8ff.js","8878:static/chunks/8878-1ab95d1f654f5058.js","8539:static/chunks/8539-3d0bbb715ba6a425.js","3234:static/chunks/3234-5172d4665c304b45.js","6628:static/chunks/6628-51ef5b07aceff5fd.js","1083:static/chunks/1083-51d2c7da64ef81a7.js","4214:static/chunks/4214-52251ceabff738d6.js","1623:static/chunks/1623-e5ed6c4108375445.js","1803:static/chunks/1803-84fbb5049df36eff.js","4585:static/chunks/4585-ba3497a793a372ad.js","4661:static/chunks/4661-744b95f516e1b044.js","3185:static/chunks/app/layout-87ea505fdc6113ce.js"],"name":"Providers","async":false}
a:I{"id":"6402","chunks":["3629:static/chunks/3629-0f2957a3da16c20f.js","8707:static/chunks/8707-2b2cb7694746a12d.js","2046:static/chunks/2046-d5dab6937324b8ff.js","8878:static/chunks/8878-1ab95d1f654f5058.js","8539:static/chunks/8539-3d0bbb715ba6a425.js","3234:static/chunks/3234-5172d4665c304b45.js","6628:static/chunks/6628-51ef5b07aceff5fd.js","1083:static/chunks/1083-51d2c7da64ef81a7.js","4214:static/chunks/4214-52251ceabff738d6.js","1623:static/chunks/1623-e5ed6c4108375445.js","1803:static/chunks/1803-84fbb5049df36eff.js","4585:static/chunks/4585-ba3497a793a372ad.js","4661:static/chunks/4661-744b95f516e1b044.js","3185:static/chunks/app/layout-87ea505fdc6113ce.js"],"name":"","async":false}
b:I{"id":"14463","chunks":["2272:static/chunks/webpack-776bf77f2147807e.js","9253:static/chunks/bce60fc1-11a2687c9c476ae2.js","6488:static/chunks/6488-777a88734e8838c1.js"],"name":"","async":false}
c:I{"id":"25786","chunks":["7601:static/chunks/app/error-706058cb55f291ca.js"],"name":"","async":false}
d:I{"id":"41941","chunks":["3629:static/chunks/3629-0f2957a3da16c20f.js","3234:static/chunks/3234-5172d4665c304b45.js","6628:static/chunks/6628-51ef5b07aceff5fd.js","1083:static/chunks/1083-51d2c7da64ef81a7.js","4214:static/chunks/4214-52251ceabff738d6.js","3757:static/chunks/3757-9aa2c71edd471806.js","1803:static/chunks/1803-84fbb5049df36eff.js","6442:static/chunks/app/connect/[provider]/redirect/page-451e9eaece45965f.js"],"name":"","async":false}
e:I{"id":"91010","chunks":["2272:static/chunks/webpack-776bf77f2147807e.js","9253:static/chunks/bce60fc1-11a2687c9c476ae2.js","6488:static/chunks/6488-777a88734e8838c1.js"],"name":"","async":false}
f:I{"id":"58478","chunks":["2180:static/chunks/0e02fca3-fd0318c0bbb142cf.js","3629:static/chunks/3629-0f2957a3da16c20f.js","8707:static/chunks/8707-2b2cb7694746a12d.js","9539:static/chunks/9539-b3a88408e4c4b614.js","2046:static/chunks/2046-d5dab6937324b8ff.js","8878:static/chunks/8878-1ab95d1f654f5058.js","3234:static/chunks/3234-5172d4665c304b45.js","3757:static/chunks/3757-9aa2c71edd471806.js","6479:static/chunks/6479-de640eb2d9b00e05.js","3681:static/chunks/3681-6021d1069ba97ac9.js","4157:static/chunks/4157-58706bf631a80bfc.js","2930:static/chunks/2930-dec6a9a498a8db8d.js","1931:static/chunks/app/page-d2ef4881464bcd6d.js"],"name":"","async":false}
7:[["$","html",null,{"lang":"en","className":"__className_98ef6d","children":["$","body",null,{"className":"bg-white text-base dark:bg-neutral-900 text-neutral-900 dark:text-neutral-200","children":["$","$L9",null,{"children":["$","$La",null,{"children":["$","$Lb",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children"],"error":"$c","errorStyles":[],"loading":["$","div",null,{"className":"flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-screen -mt-24","children":[["$","$Ld",null,{}],"$undefined"]}],"loadingStyles":[],"hasLoading":true,"template":["$","$Le",null,{}],"templateStyles":"$undefined","notFound":["$","div",null,{"className":"flex flex-col justify-center items-center mt-24","children":[["$","h2",null,{"className":"text-2xl font-semibold","children":"404: Page not found "}],["$","a",null,{"href":"/","className":"mt-8","children":"Go back to home"}]]}],"notFoundStyles":[],"childProp":{"current":[["$","main",null,{"className":"nc-PageHome relative","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"container pb-24 lg:pb-28","children":["$","$Lf",null,{}]}]}],null],"segment":"__PAGE__"},"styles":[]}]}]}]}]}],null]
8:[["$","meta","0",{"charSet":"utf-8"}],["$","title","1",{"children":"Directimo - Top Vacation Homes in Top Desination"}],["$","meta","2",{"name":"description","content":"Directimo - Top Vacation Homes in Top Desination"}],["$","meta","3",{"name":"viewport","content":"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"}],["$","link","4",{"rel":"icon","href":"/favicon.ico","type":"image/x-icon","sizes":"any"}]]
```

Next version: `13.4.5` - app directory

[image]

I've deployed the app on digital ocean - App platform.

On localhost I'm not able to reproduce it

Tried to change next version but with no luck

Comment: Hi, did you figure anything out here? We occasionally get this issue ourselves. On digitalocean, where the solution is to just deploy again.. 

We have our own localization solution based on the [lang] router idea.

Comment: Hi did you figure it out? @AndreasHalvorsenTollånes?

Comment: @Akar yes I did will update with the answer, simply an possible early return in an layout component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was when we got the same result.

It was as simple as there existing a possibly early return statement in one of the few layout files we had in the project. We simply removed it and instead of returning early we provided a default value to said property that created the early return.

EG: return null if no dictionary found was bad, forcefully give English dictionary to the property instead. We have not seen the issue since.